# Golang lambda upload image into s3 static website

Tags: image, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an existing go webserver that has a route that accepts form elements (one of which is a file) and uploads the resulting file (after resizing and renaming) into the images folder that the webserver serves up. I am changing the application to use lambda (go) and a static website on s3. Other things like storing the information on MongoDB (aws hosted), I understand completely.

I know that I need to add the PutObject permissions on the website bucket. Again in s3 I have an images folder... Does anyone have an example similar? All the code on the AWS github repo has the file going to the bucket (not a folder in the bucket like images).

Again I need to resize the image (write to /tmp in lambda?), and upload to the folder in the s3 bucket.

Any examples or ideas regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "not a folder in the bucket like images" S3 has no folders.  If you want to upload to "images/filename.jpg" instead of "filename.jpg", just upload with the key of "images/filename.jpg"

Comment: Thanks..... Do you have an example in go?

Comment: Requests for examples are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and it's unclear what the [aws docs example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/gov2/s3/actions/bucket_basics.go#L109) is missing (as per the above comment, just amend this with something like `Key: aws.String("images/filename.jpg")` to [simulate a folder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html))